# Reduce the integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

For each nonnegative integer $n$, there exists a polynomial $p_n(x)$ such that
$$\int x^ne^xdx=p_n(x)e^x+C$$
Let
$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|p_n(2)|}{n!}$$
Find $⌊1000L⌋$.

Comment: $p_n$ is of degree $n$, it growths slower that $n!$, the limit is $0$. Are you missing something in your question?

Comment: Who said $p_n(x)$ is of degree of $n$?

Comment: It can be easily checked by taking derivative on both sides. And the integral just gives incomplete gamma function.

Comment: @math110 gave a nice answer already. The limit is not $0$ as i forgot the coefficients also depend on $n$.

Answer (score 7):

Let $$I_{n}=\int x^ne^xdx=x^ne^x-n\int e^xx^{n-1}dx=x^ne^x-nI_{n-1}$$
so
$$I_{n}=x^ne^x-n(x^{n-1}e^x-(n-1)I_{n-2})=e^xx^n-nx^{n-1}e^x+n(n-1)x^{n-2}e^x-n(n-1)(n-2)I_{n-3}=\cdots$$
we have
$$I_{n}=e^{x}\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^i\dfrac{n!}{(n-i)!}x^{n-i}=e^x\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-i}\dfrac{n!}{i!}x^i$$
so
$$\dfrac{|P_{n}(2)|}{n!}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^{i}\dfrac{2^i}{i!}$$
so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{|P_{n}(2)|}{n!}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{i}\dfrac{2^i}{i!}=e^{-2}$$
so
$$[1000L]=[1000e^{-2}]=135$$

Comment: I don't know what you have done wrong, but all I know is that your answer is wrong. Please find the mistake(I can't). Nice try. +1.

Comment: @math110 Shouldn't that be $e^{-2}$?

Comment: This was what I was about to write.

Comment: sorry,I have edit it.